# Symfony2 Change form behaviour based on option

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form that I want to use for both an and edit, but want to change the fields and validation accordingly.

I am changing what the form displays by looking at the '*name*' option passed when running the `createForm` method in the controller.
In controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $form = $this->createForm('client', $client, array('name' => 'add'));

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $client->save();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:client:clientAdd.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

In the ClientType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id');

    if ('add' === $options['name']) {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    if ('edit' === $options['name']) {
        $builder->add('age');
    }

    $builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'Save'
    ));
}
```

The validation (as defined in my validation.yml) has rules for all fields and it will throw an error for the field in add mode that is not present.
How can I get the validation to be conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See validation groups http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups
and form validation groups http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups